# Default deleter for raw pointer in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc, unique-ptr

Is it safe to rely on default deleter using `std::unique_ptr`?

I want to use it like this:

```
uint8_t* binaryData = new uint8_t[binaryDataSize];
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> binPtr(binaryData);
```

So the default deleter in `std::unique_ptr` looks like this:

```
template<typename _Up>
typename enable_if<is_convertible<_Up(*)[], _Tp(*)[]>::value>::type
operator()(_Up* __ptr) const
{
    static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
                  "can't delete pointer to incomplete type");
    delete [] __ptr;
}
```

From my point of view it's safe to use for raw pointers allocated by `new[]` and not safe with raw pointers allocated by `std::malloc`.
Am i missing something? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Define "better". I would likely use a `std::vector` and avoid the problem.

Comment: For pointers allocated with `new[]` you should be using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. In your case, `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So the default deleter in `std::unique_ptr` looks like this:

That's the default deleter for arrays. You will only hit that deleter when using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, not when using `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

---

> From my point of view it's safe to use for raw pointers allocated by `new[]`

As long as you use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, yes. You should use `std::make_unique` to avoid these issues.

---

> raw pointers allocated by `std::malloc`

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't support pointers allocated with `malloc`. Regardless, you shouldn't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `std::unique_ptr` *does* support pointers allocated with `std::malloc()` - by allowing you to specify an appropriate deleter.  That can be useful when interfacing with C libraries, for example.

Answer (score 2):

That should be `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`, otherwise the default deleter is not that one but the one that calls plain `delete`, and that mismatch will trigger UB.

You cannot use the default deleter at all if you allocated with `std::malloc`, you'll need to provide your own deleter that calls `std::free`.